# Problem separating homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following homogeneous differential equation:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+3y}{3x+y}
$$

As I understand it, I have to use a substitution, either $y = ux, dy=u\,dx+x\,du$ or $x=uy, dx=u\,dy+y\,du$. So I try to substitute either, and I get stuck because I'm not having a separated equation I can integrate. Here's what I have done so far:

Using the first substitution:
$$
\frac{u\,dx+x\,du}{dx}=\frac{x+3ux}{3x+ux} \\
(3x+ux)(u\,dx+x\,du)=(x+3ux)dx \\
3x^2\,du+ux^2\,du=x\,dx-u^2x\,dx\\
3\,du+u\,du=\frac{dx}{x}-\frac{u^2\,dx}{x}
$$
But at this point, dividing by $u^2$ will make me have the following term: $\frac{dx}{u^2x}$, and this is where I'm stuck, as I cannot separate. I checked my algebra to make sure I didn't blunder, and I *think* I'm clear (I hope). Using the second substitution yields a similar result:

$$
\frac{dy}{u\,dy+uy\,du}=\frac{uy+3y}{3uy+y} \\
y\,dy-u^2y\,dy=3y^2\,du+uy^2\,du \\
\frac{dy}{y}-\frac{u^2\,dy}{y}=3\,du+u\,du
$$

Any pointer in the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: so for completeness sake, thanks to the answer and comment provided:

$$
\frac{u\,dx+x\,du}{dx}=\frac{x+3ux}{3x+ux} \\
\frac{u\,dx+x\,du}{dx}=\frac{x(1+3u)}{x(3+u)} \\
\frac{u\,dx+x\,du}{dx}=\frac{1+3u}{3+u} \\
(u\,dx+x\,du)(3+u)=(1+3u)dx \\
3u\,dx+u^2\,dx+3x\,du+ux\,du=dx+3u\,dx \\
u^2\,dx+2x\,du+ux\,du=dx \\
3x\,du+u\,du=\frac{dx}{x}-\frac{u^2\,dx}{x} \\
(3+u)\,du=(1-u^2)\frac{dx}{x} \\
\frac{3+u}{1-u^2}\,du=\frac{dx}{x} \\
\frac{3\,du}{1-u^2}+\frac{u\,du}{1-u^2}=\frac{dx}{x} \\
\int{\frac{3\,du}{1-u^2}}+\int{\frac{u\,du}{1-u^2}}=\int{\frac{dx}{x}}
$$

Which is now solvable. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you had cancelled $x$ from $$\frac{udx+xdu}{dx}=\frac{x(1+3u}{x(3+u}$$ then you were able to separate.

Comment: @Qurultay thanks, you hint made me arrive at Lutz' answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that
$$
\frac{3+u}{1-u^2}du=\frac{dx}x
$$
is quite separated already.

Comment: Thank you, your answer together with @Qurultay 's tip I managed to separate the variables (I mean, got the same answer you posted). Now I'll just integrate. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+3y}{3x+y}$$
Easy way:
$$\frac{dy}{x+3y}=\frac{dx}{3x+y}$$
Now it's separable:
$$\frac{d(x+y)}{2(x+y)}=\frac{d(x-y)}{(x-y)}$$
Integrate.